# why my pelican static blog generator gives a flick before rendering

Tags: css, pelican

I just moved from wordpress to pelican static blog. Now the problem is, the blog take a bit time to apply the CSS and its clearly visible to the user in the browser [here is teh link](http://neps.in)

This is generally appeared in web pages where CSS are put in the bottom. So there will be redraw of the DOM after the rendition. But CSS are in the top but still why I am seeing this.

Pls clarify. and Suggest some solution.

Thanks

Comment: Hi nepsdotin, questions asking "why isn't my code working" require that you include that code (just enough to reproduce the error) in the question itself, rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: Hi @TylerH Thanks for your time. Actually I don't have a particular code. Its a problem with the full site. Hence I have linked that. Let me know if you need any other info.